# display : none in Worklight project

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst

Just got curious on beginning to work on IBM Worklight... Why does the body tag always have style = "display:none" in the main JS file of a Worklight project? That doesn't seem to have any effect either...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically it does. You don't want your mobile app to be loaded similarly to the way web site MIGHT be loaded, e.g. first you see some html elements, then you see more elements, then CSS has finished loading and you see styles, then JS has finished loading and after some processing your UI was modified again etc. On the contrary - you want your app to look the way it should look from the first moment. This is where display:none comes handy. User will not see the UI until wlCommonInit/wlEnvInit function has returned - which means WL framework has finished initializing and developer's initialization code is done running. Once this happens WL framework assumes that developer finished preparing his UI and updates css display property to block making UI visible.

It is not mandatory to use this, you can remove display:none from body element. However in this case it is up to developer to control app UI during initialization.